# Getting Undefiend when using a variable on getting JSON value

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I got the following node.js code snippet that do a swithch statement:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(file);
app.post('/save', function (req, res) {
    switch (config_value){
        case 'data1':
            config_to_pass.A[0] = req.body;
            break;
        case 'data2':
            config_to_pass.B[0] = req.body;
            break;
   }
}
```

The config_value is the key on the json like A, B, C and so on. The above code works, but then what I want to do is `config_to_pass.config_value[0]` im getting undefiend. I want to do the following logic because what if I add more keys like D, E, F i need to change the code.

Comment: post a more detailed code, illustrating where you declared `config_value`, where you're making the calling which returns `undefined`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
var obj = JSON.parse(file);
app.post('/save', function (req, res) {
    config_to_pass[config_value] = req.body;
}
```

or:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(file);
app.post('/save', function (req, res) {
    config_to_pass[config_value][0] = req.body;
}
```

By the way, it's better to include some response, even something like:

```
res.json({ok: true});
```

inside of your handler. Otherwise the request will hang and timeout.

Comment: Thanks sir, the 2nd one helped me. I remembe trying that but i added . after the config_to_pass. I will add your suggestion. Thank you again